# React Native - get url search params

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to get URL params in a React Native app.

What I tried to do:

1. fails because searchParams is an empty list

```
const parsedUrl = new URL(url)

// here the searchParams are empty list
console.log(parsedUrl.searchParams)
```

2. fails because the following error is shown:

> [Error: not implemented]

```
const parsedUrl = new URLSearchParams(url)
console.log(parsedUrl.get(param))
```

Comment: Could you provide an example url that contains values you want to acess?

Comment: myapp://?code=123123-1123123-418c-33213-123123

Comment: You should look into deep linking: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/ that is the way urls work on mobile devices and apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const getSearchParamFromURL = (url, param) => {
  const include = url.includes(param)

  if (!include) return null

  const params = url.split(/([&,?,=])/)
  const index = params.indexOf(param)
  const value = params[index + 2]
  return value
}

const _url = 'myapp://?code=123123-1123123-418c-33213-123123&param_key=param_value'

getSearchParamFromURL(_url, 'code') // output: 123123-1123123-418c-33213-123123
```

Comment: This seems to solve the wrong problem, the question is about retrieving the parameter value not parsing the parameter value

Comment: This solves the question, however, there are some cases where it will fail... I will edit to improve.

Answer (score 5):

You Can Try this:

( Only For React Js )

```js
function getURLParams(parameterName, url) {
  let name = parameterName.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  let regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'), results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return null;
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

// For Current Window URL
console.log(getURLParams("param1", window.location.href));

// For Custom URL
console.log(getURLParams("param1", "https://example.com/index.html?param1=Hello"));
```

Or This

( For React Native )

```js
var url = "http://example.com?param1=test&param2=someData&number=123"

var regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
  params = {},
  match;
while (match = regex.exec(url)) {
  params[match[1]] = match[2];
}

console.log(params)
```

Comment: Does this also work for react native? This seems to be browser-only?

Comment: Ah yea i forgot to add for react native, now i have update the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do in my custom `Link.tsx` component in react-navigation 5:

```
export const Link = function Link({ to, action, target, onPress, children, params }: Props) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params as Record<string, string>)

  return (
    <DefaultLink
      to={`${to.startsWith('/') ? to : `/${to}`}${params ? `?${searchParams.toString()}` : ''}`}
      action={action}
      target={target}
      onPress={onPress}>
      {children}
    </DefaultLink>
  )
}
```

If you are also using react-navigation, you can use `pathConfig.parse` and `pathConfig.stringify` to automatically convert the typing. [`getStateFromPath`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/getStateFromPath.tsx)|[`getPathFromState`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/getPathFromState.tsx)